# C# reload iframe content from inside

Tags: c#

I have a button and an iframe (src is homepageaspx) in my sitemaster page.

When I click on that button, iframe loads another page (registeruseraspx) correctly.

Now in this new page (registeruseraspx) I have a button; when I click on this button, I want that the iframe loads a new aspx page.

I've tryed to dinamically change the src attribute of the iframe from registeruseraspx but nothing happens.

Please help me

Comment: Is it really necessary to iframe your own pages? Or do you misunderstand how to use the Master page?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: it may be parent or main page of the site he is referring as site master page.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the page of the iframe within the iframe (using javascript):

```
self.location.replace('your_new_page.aspx');

//add above javascript line to the onclick event of the button
//on registeruser.aspx page
<input id="myButton"
       type="button" 
       value="Iframe Button" 
       onclick="self.location.replace('your_new_page.aspx');" />
```

Using code behind page of registeruser.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "self.location.replace('your_new_page.aspx')");
    }
}
```